# How do I get scripts running again if the AppsScript service has been throttled?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I added this bound script to a google sheet trying to save time by not having to manually enter the sheetname in a cell:

```
function sheetname() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
}
```

Then I realised it wasn't stable so I stopped calling it from inside the sheet `=sheetname()`. Then I forgot about it at went on duplicating my sheet (with this bound script) to over 1000 new files.

Now I need to create a stand alone script for a different purpose, but when saving it to be able to run the script I get this message:

> "The service has been used many times in a day: dev console project
>   create Attempts."

I managed to save the script project once but then when I tried to run it I got this slightly different error message:

> Error saving project: too many scripts created in one day for this
>   Google user account.

So I figured: fine, I'll have to wait a day and not duplicate the file with the bound script during that time. But that didn't work. So now I seem to be stuck with here without the possibility to every add a script again from my account.

From what I understand, the bound scripts can only be accessed and disabled/deleted through each of the duplicated Google sheets script editor.

**Will I ever be able to add scripts again without having to open my 1000 duplicates and delete each one of the bound script? Or by deleting the 1000 duplicates and start over? If so how?**

I've already put in too many hours manually connecting each duplicated file to a master sheet manually with `importrange`.

Comment: Does [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5518), or the one it was merged to, fit your situation? Neither suggests a solution, but on the other hand it's very odd that the quota does not recover in 24 hours.

Comment: The issue linked above by 404 fit my situation pretty good. Sorry about the title, this is better. I feel really resigned here. Just had a lot of people put in way to many hours in this project and now it seems like we have to trow it alla away and start over because I forgot about this silly bound script attached to the file I duplicated.

Comment: One more thing: I managed to save the script project once but then when I tried to run it I got this slightly different error message: "Error saving project: too many scripts created in one day for this Google user account."

Comment: Do you think I might be able to work around this by creating a new google account, share the project to that account and then try to run the script from that account? Or is it only the owner of files that can run scripts. Getting desperate here.

Comment: Anyone with edit access to a script, or a file to which the script is bound, can run the script - they will need to authorize it, and it will run from their account. Yes, creating another account is reasonable. I use a few to distribute scripting load.

Comment: This ULR `https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1` should give you a display of all the scripts and you can revoke access there. I don't see any bulk removal options but you could probably write a browser plugin to do it w/o too much effort.

Comment: I tried creating a new account but got the same error: "Error saving project: too many scripts created in one day for this Google user account". The new account _never_ created a singel script.

Comment: Did you already posted a issue to [Google Apps  Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)?

Comment: @johlund Were you able to solve it? I am having the same issue... =/

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, the bound scripts can only be accessed and disabled/deleted through each of the duplicated Google sheets script editor.

Recently Google launched the [Google Apps Script Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dashboard). From there we could "Delete forever" bounded scripts without having to open the container.