# Error saving project: too many scripts created in one day

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I duplicated about 800 spreadsheets with the container-bound script in a day.
As a result, when I launch the duplicated container-bound script or I launch a new script, I get the following error:

“ Error saving project: too many scripts created in one day for this Google user account. ”

Perhaps the following questions or bug reports are relevant?

- [How do I get scripts running again if the AppsScript service has been throttled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706061/how-do-i-get-scripts-running-again-if-the-appsscript-service-has-been-throttled)
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63078880

It's been a day since the error appeared, but the situation hasn't changed and the error appears.

Is there upper limit for creating scripts that an account can create?
At what pace will the error be resolved?

Comment: In a script that gives the error, the same error will occur for other accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is **50 Apps Script projects per day**.

You have to wait 24 hrs, but sometimes it takes a little longer.

Google quotas:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas